# see if parent is checkbox

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How can I check if "this" is a checkbox?

This is the way to see if it is an selectbox

```
if($(this).parent().is('select'))   {
```

Now can I see wether it is a checkbox? So I tried this:

```
 }else if($(this).is(:Checkbox)){\n
```

But it gives me a syntax error. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkbox:

```
if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) ...
```

Checked:

```
if ($(this).is(":checkbox:checked")) ...
```

Consult [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
if($(this).is(':checkbox'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want some easy code for that then u can check like that ..

var id = jQuery(this).attr('type');
id will give you type of that like checkbox,select

i tried that one it is working fine for me..

alert(id);